# Access SQL Server in Hadoop

Tags: sql-server, hadoop

What I want to do:
  The program is designed to load regional sales data from SQL Server 2008 and run simple statistics computation on MapReduce to get total sales in each regions. The erro I got says the program can't find the sqljdbc4.jar file, however,  the file did had copied into the location specified in code.

1. So the code likes:

   ```
   //fileName: MRExp.java
   public class MRExp {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           JobConf conf = new JobConf(MRExp.class);
           DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/userX/sqljdbc4.jar"), conf);

           conf.setMapperClass(MRMapper.class);
           conf.setReducerClass(MRReducer.class);

           conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
           conf.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

           conf.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
           conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

           conf.setInputFormat(DBInputFormat.class);
           FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));

           DBConfiguration
                   .configureDB(
                           conf,
                           "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                           "jdbc:sqlserver://MyDbServerAddr:1433;databaseName=ThisDb;integratedSecurity=true;",
                           "db_userName", "db_Pws");

           DBInputFormat
                   .setInput(conf, InfoUnit.class,
                           "SELECT R_NAME,L_ORDERKEY from dbo.United10MB ;"/* inputQuery */
                           , "SELECT COUNT(L_ORDERKEY) from dbo.United10MB"/* inputCountQuery */);

           try {
               JobClient.runJob(conf);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   //followed by the definition of MRMapper and MRReducer and InfoUnit. InfoUnit implements Writable, DBWritable.
2. Files Location:

   [root@test MRExp]# pwd
   /root/MRExp
   [root@test MRExp]# ls
   classes  hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar  MRExp.java  sqljdbc4.jar
3. Then, for compiling MRExp.java:

   [root@test MRExp]#  javac -classpath hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar -d classes/ MRExp.java
   [root@test MRExp]#  jar -cvf MRExp.jar -C classes/ .

but also copying sqljdbc4.jar to HDFS:

```
[root@test MRExp]#  hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal sqljdbc4.jar /userX
```

so we get:

```
[root@test MRExp]# ls  
classes  hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar  MRExp.jar  MRExp.java  sqljdbc4.jar
```

1. After the above, fire the MapR Process:

   [root@test MRExp]#  hadoop jar MRExp.jar mrexp.MRExp /userX/output

But the program says:

```
17:02:50 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/10/28 17:02:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1350984913454_0009
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getInputFormat(JobConf.java:607)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1223)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:604)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:880)
        at mrexp.MRExp.main(MRExp.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:159)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:185)
        ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the sqljdbc4.jar JAR in the “-libjars” command line option of the `hadoop jar …` command.

Please read [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) post from Cloudera for more information.

**UPDATE:**

Do the following

```
[root@test MRExp]#  hadoop dfs -ls /userX
```

Copy the absolute path to your sqljdbc4.jar in your file system and put in the following line

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("<Absolute Path>/sqljdbc4.jar"), conf);
```

This will fix the issue.